ArcGIS Online - can't add Power BI domain
I would like to fire up the ArcGIS Online in the PowerBI environment. Unfortunately, it looks like I've encountered a serious problem.
Namely for whatever reason I am unable to add the domain to the  Allow origins section like you see below:

I used this guideline as a reference
https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/restrict-cross-domain-requests-to-your-portal.htm
Can anyone help me sort it out?

What version are you on?   10.9.1+ had some changes

This is ArcGIS Online, so i believe there is no version
